# Enviar link pelo PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estou tentando enviar um e-mail de confirmação de cadastro para um cliente usando o [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Acontece que a mensagem é impressa conforme abaixo:

```
<strong>Você foi cadastrado no sistema de licitação da Terra Palmas.</strong>
Clique no link para confirmar seu e-mail:
<a href='http://pt.stackoverflow.com/cliente/confirmar/'> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/cliente/confirmar/</a>
```

Em seguida o código usado:

```
$mailTo->Body = "
    <strong>Você foi cadastrado no sistema de licitação da Terra Palmas.</strong>
    Clique no link para confirmar seu e-mail:
    <a href='{$link}'> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/cliente/confirmar/</a>
";
```

Quem pode me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado? Já pesquisei bastante e não consigo resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Se você está utilizando dentro de um `<a></a>`, por exemplo, você deve ter certeza de que habilitou o modo `html`. Isso significa que ele vai processar o seu código `html` e imprimir tudo corretamente. Para isso, basta utilizar essa opção:

```
$mailTo->IsHTML(true);
```

Isso deve resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Obrigado Celsom